# Codeigniter:value getting appended from an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter

```
public function func1()
{
    $this->func();
    $result1 = $this->result;

    foreach ($result1 as $row) {
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('place');

        $string = '';

        $string = $row[state_name];

        $this->db->where('state'=,"$string");
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

where `$this->func();` is getting an array containing an array of strings of names and I am using each value as condition in `where` clause in `func1(select)`. I'm using A `foreach` loop to get each string from resultset of `func` and later on I'm trying to select a name matched from where clause in `func1` but I am getting below error

```
A Database Error Occurred
    Error Number: 1064
    SELECT `name` FROM (`place`) WHERE `state=` 'place1,place2, place3,place4';
```

all the values from `foreach` is getting appended to the same query , where in my case each iteration should have fetched only one value and executed the `SELECT` query and returned the result.

Comment: `$this->db->where('state'=,"$string");` is that a typo? as the `=` is outside of `'state'`. There is also a typo here `$string = $row[state_name];` unless `state_name` is a constant?

Comment: `$this->db->where('state',"$string");` remove `=`

Comment: Also, I'm guessing $this->func is not returning an array of values but all the values appended, check your func() to see what it returns, and correct your where statement as mentioned by Noor

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
public function func1()
{
    $this->func();
    $result1 = $this->result;

    $data = null; $i=0;
    foreach ($result1 as $row) {
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('place');

        $string = '';

        $string = $row['state_name'];

        $this->db->where('state'=,"$string");
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $query->result_array();
        $data[$i] = $query->result_array;
    }
  return $data;

}
```